# Parallelize SparkSession in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I would like to do calculations for getting top 5 keywords in each country and inside the method to get top 5 keywords, is there any way I can parallelize SparkSessions?

Now I am doing

```
country_mapping_df.rdd.map(lambda country_tuple: get_top_5_keywords(country_tuple))

def get_top_5_keywords(country_tuple):
    result1 = spark.sql("""sample""")
    result.write_to_s3
```

which is not working! Anyone knows how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark does not support two contexts/Sessions running concurrently in the same program, Hence you can not parallelize SparkSessions.

source: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#unit-testing